# Why INPLACE_ADD is faster than the INPLACE_SUBTRACT in python?

Tags: python, bytecode

It all begin with Raymond Hettinger's [tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1131103570856632321) about Alternative Increment Operator aka *Space Invador Operator*

I wanted to check the performance of both `+=` and `-=-` operators using the module [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

**Python 3**

```
python3 -m timeit "for i in range(1000000): i+=1"                   
python3 -m timeit "for i in range(1000000): i-=-1"
```

**output:**

```
10 loops, best of 5: 35.9 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 5: 36.6 msec per loop
```

**Python 2**

```
python -m timeit "for i in range(1000000): i+=1"
python -m timeit "for i in range(1000000): i-=-1"
```

**output:**

```
10 loops, best of 5: 35.7 msec per loop               
10 loops, best of 5: 36.7 msec per loop
```

Notice that, in both Python 2 and Python 3, `+=` is faster than `-=-` by almost `1msec` even though the results of both operations is simply incrementing the variable `i` by 1.

See below the byte code instructions generated for these two operators using [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def io(i): i+=1
>>> def aio(i): i-=-1
>>> dis.dis(io)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 INPLACE_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(aio)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              4 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

The only difference is the `INPLACE_ADD` and `INPLACE_SUBTRACT` instructions the rest of the instructions are almost identical.